# Calculate functional determinant $\det(\partial_x)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider functional determinants of differential operators as described in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant#Path_integral_version) Wikipedia article. I would like to calculate this result for a simple example

$$\det(\partial_x)$$

for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or $x\in[0,L]$ or similar.

The general solution to the eigenvalue problem

$$\partial_x f_i(x)=\lambda_i f_i(x)$$

is

$$f_i(x)=c_i e^{\lambda_i x}$$

for any coefficient $c_i$. However, there does not seem to be any restriction on what the $\lambda_i$ or $c_i$ should be. If I understand correctly, the determinant then would be $\prod_i\lambda_i$. But how to get these values?